# PostgreSQL Serialisation failure on different ids

Tags: postgresql, isolation-level, upsert, serialization

Serializable isolation mode can be used to avoid race conditions when upserting equal ids. So for `create table u(uid int primary key, name text);` if we run two similar transactions T1 and T2:

```
begin isolation level serializable;
select * from u where uid = 1;
```

And then continue with for T1 and T2:

```
insert into u (uid, name) values (1, 'A');
```

After `commit;` only the first succeeds while the other throws a serialisation failure.

This is a very neat feature of the mode to handle unique key violations in complex transactions and not resorting to a specific 'hack' `insert ... on conflict`. **However** even if uids are different, say `uid = 2` and `uid = 3`, both transactions T1 and T2 **still won't** be able to commit.

How could it be possible? Supposedly they create different predicate SIReadlocks and `select` uses index scan. Where's the trick?

Comment: Sorry for confusion @jjanes. I get serialisation failure, which essentially hides unique key violation.

Comment: @jjanes I use Postgres 11.5 with two psql connections open. After creating a table, in each terminal window I put: `begin isolation level serializable;` For T1 I add: `select * from u where uid = 2;` and for T2: `select * from u where uid = 3;` After they reveal 'no rows' result, I do T1: `insert into u (uid, name) values (2, 'A');` and T2: `insert into u (uid, name) values (3, 'B');` I commit T1, which succeeds, but T2 on `commit;` returns 'could not serialize access due to read/write dependencies among transactions'.

Comment: @jjanes 100%. Do you do the same sequence of commands?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97825/discussion-between-yury-oparin-and-jjanes).

Comment: Your comment would do better as an edit than a comment.  I can reproduce your results, but I don't know why it works that way.  Making it easier to read might attract more attention.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is that the table is completely empty.

See the following code in `_bt_first` in `src/backend/access/nbtree/nbtsearch.c`:

```
if (!BufferIsValid(buf))
{
    /*
     * We only get here if the index is completely empty. Lock relation
     * because nothing finer to lock exists.
     */
    PredicateLockRelation(rel, scan->xs_snapshot);
[...]
    return false;
}
else
    PredicateLockPage(rel, BufferGetBlockNumber(buf),
                      scan->xs_snapshot);
```

Normally, the index scan would put an `SIRead` lock on the index page where the index entry should be, but since the index is empty, PostgreSQL resorts to putting an `SIRead` lock on the whole table.

Now since both transactions do that, you get a serialization error at the end of one of them, because the writes conflict with the table-wide read lock.

If the table were *not* empty, you would notice that concurrent transactions like these sometimes succeed, because they affect different index pages. If the affected `uid`s are sufficiently close together that they are on the same index page, you would still experience a “false positive” serialization error. This [is documented](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/transaction-iso.html#XACT-SERIALIZABLE):

> While PostgreSQL's Serializable transaction isolation level only allows concurrent transactions to commit if it can prove there is a serial order of execution that would produce the same effect, it doesn't always prevent errors from being raised that would not occur in true serial execution. In particular, it is possible to see unique constraint violations caused by conflicts with overlapping Serializable transactions even after explicitly checking that the key isn't present before attempting to insert it.

To see what kind of `SIReadLock` PostgreSQL uses, inspect `pg_locks`.

Comment: I could reproduce the problem and have modified the answer accordingly.

Comment: What an insight into the code, bravo! Unfortunately, even after populating `u` with `insert into u(uid, name) select x.id, 'A' || x.id form generate_series(1,100000) AS x(id);` and running `ANALYZE u;`, I still get a serialisation failure for `uid = 100001` and `uid=100002`.

Comment: Then they are locking the same index page. I'll update the answer to explain that better.

Comment: Index page locking in fact only happens with 'new' selects. So If we consider another case with select + update (instead of 'insert') even for adjacent uid = 1 and uid = 2, the first time the last transaction to commit will throw a serialisation failure on read/write dependencies like for the select + insert case, but a second time the same sequence of queries will result in both transactions succeeding.

Comment: Actually, the whole index page gets 'loaded' and within it no false positives occur later.

Comment: The only sad thing about the answer is that I haven't been able to actually verify index page locking behaviour for select + insert. Assuming that `uid` is an 'int' type and so takes 4 bytes, an 8k page would contain 8*1024/4 = 2048 values. So I first filled the table with 2047 values and then tried to run the test with `uid = 2048` and `uid = 2049`. But still had the same serialisation failure.

Comment: Look for page locks in `pg_locks`.

Comment: It is not so important why exactly a certain transaction receives a false positive serialization error. You just have to be ready to repeat the transaction.